# Log user activity on various platforms

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, user-activity

I have an Electron app and I need to log system-wide user activity (e.g. mouse-clicks, keystrokes). Basically, i need to detect if user is AFK if he did nothing in a 5-minute interval, so i can stop the timer inside the app. I'm pretty sure I need to do it with external scripts for each platform (osx, linux, ms). Can you guys suggest me any finished tools or os-level APIs to do it (doesn't matter for which plat) if you know some, or just tell me how you would do it / did it some time.

Answer (score 0):

For all platform monitoring and analysis use GrayLog
https://www.graylog.org/